# Wordpress get parameter 'unapproved' and 'moderation-hash'

Tags: urls, site-url, parameter

I have a blog site. And I found a suspicious access to my blog post from log.
The url format is like this.

```
https://example.com/my-post/?unapproved=420&moderation-hash=847492149d817bf7e08d81457bf9952f
```

And they access from several ips. What is their purpose?

Comment: It could be an attempt at spamming: [see this Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49956).

Answer (score 1):

Spammers use the URL of unapproved comments to share around the Internet. This makes the comments viewable until the comment is dealt with via approval process.

WordPress' contributors are working on a patch for the next version. 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49956

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos($url,'/?') !== false) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />' . "\n";
    }
?>
```

This is one of the solutions, you can hide pages with GET parameters from the search. Just add it to the header.php file

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem here: it sounds to me like people are sharing the moderation URLs, not having them picked up by search engines.